# How to duplicate (not distribute/load-balance !) incoming http traffic to multiple servers?

Tags: http, iis, nginx

I would like to create a setup where each incoming http request that matches a given rule (say url/headers-based regex) will be duplicated and dispatched to N upstream HTTP servers with the response used being from one of them (say the first).

Commmon rewriting tasks (url, headers) could be specified for each of the N upstream requests amd ideally this would work with all HTTP verbs but just GET and POST would be ok too.

What should I be looking at ? (bonus for windows based solution, two bonuses (bonusi?) for IIS-based one).

I know it is rather simple to write a rudimentary version of the above in node/python/etc but I'm looking for something mature that can be deployed in production.

Comment: You'll have more luck asking this kind of question on https://serverfault.com/ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Network Load Balancing with IIS may fit your request.
http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/configuring-servers-in-the-windows-web-platform/network-load-balancing